# MYSQL change storage engine of table from INNODB to MYISAM

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have about 10million records of data in a table(innodb as storage). I normally get max locks exceeded when i perform mass edits, inserts and additions to it. Upon reading some help tips i want to convert the table to MyISAM and see if there will be some improvements.

but when i try to change the storage type from innodb to myisam in phpmyadmin, i get 'Number of locks exceeded error'

1. Is it good to change to myIsam?
2. What proceedure do i use to avoid getting 'max no. of locks exceeded error?'

thanks

Comment: ok. but how then can i avoid these locks errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a very bad idea to change to MyISAM. You'll lose transaction support and the database won't be journaled meaning a crash could easily corrupt it beyond recoverability.

You can adjust the lock time-out parameter for the server to give operations a longer time to complete. For batch operations this is essential. This is the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` configuration parameter you can adjust manually or set in `my.cnf`. This is normally very low, typically 50 seconds, so many big operations will fail unless this is changed.

You should also make a point of removing any indexes that aren't strictly required as this may  be the source of a lot of the delays. `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will give you an idea of how much index space is associated with your tables. Larger indexes are more expensive to maintain, especially when doing mass-inserts.

Comment: ok. thanks. i checked the  index_lenght of the table and it is 167034880. what does it mean?